# Method not getting called in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.taking_quiz);

    que = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQuestion);
    opt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    opt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    opt3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    opt4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    qn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
    sco = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    qn.setText("1");
    sco.setText("Score : 0");
    qn.setText("Question : 1");

    RecieversId = getIntent().getStringExtra("Recievers_Id");

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(RecieversId).child("Quiz").child("Question" + mQuestionNumber);

    updateQuestion();

}

private void updateQuestion() {

    if (mDatabaseReference != null) {
        mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String question = dataSnapshot.child("Question").getValue().toString();
                answer = dataSnapshot.child("Answer").getValue().toString();
                option1 = dataSnapshot.child("Option1").getValue().toString();
                option2 = dataSnapshot.child("Option2").getValue().toString();
                option3 = dataSnapshot.child("Option3").getValue().toString();
                option4 = dataSnapshot.child("Option4").getValue().toString();
                que.setText(question);
                opt1.setText(option1);
                opt2.setText(option2);
                opt3.setText(option3);
                opt4.setText(option4);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

        opt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (option1.equals(answer)) {
                    opt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    mScore++;
                    sco.setText("Score : " + mScore);
                } else
                    opt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                sco.setText("Score : " + mScore);
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mQuestionNumber++;
                        qn.setText("Question : " + mQuestionNumber);
                        updateQuestion();
                        opt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                    }
                }, 1500);
            }
        });
        opt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (option2.equals(answer)) {
                    opt2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    mScore++;
                    sco.setText("Score : " + mScore);
                } else
                    opt2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                sco.setText("Score : " + mScore);
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mQuestionNumber++;
                        qn.setText("Question : " + mQuestionNumber);
                        updateQuestion();
                        opt2.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                    }
                }, 1500);
            }
        });
        opt3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (option3.equals(answer)) {
                    opt3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    mScore++;
                } else
                    opt3.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                sco.setText("Score : " + mScore);
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mQuestionNumber++;
                        qn.setText("Question : " + mQuestionNumber);
                        updateQuestion();
                        opt3.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                    }
                }, 1500);
            }
        });
        opt4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (option4.equals(answer)) {
                    opt4.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    mScore++;
                    sco.setText("Score : " + mScore);
                } else
                    opt4.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                sco.setText("Score : " + mScore);
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mQuestionNumber++;
                        qn.setText("Question : " + mQuestionNumber);
                        updateQuestion();
                        opt4.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                    }
                }, 1500);
            }
        });
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(TakingQuiz.this, TakingQuizDone.class);
        intent.putExtra("Score", mScore);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make a quiz app in Android using a firebase database.
When you click on one of the buttons (answer the question) the question number will increase and according to that question will also increase.
But the ++ is working and the `TextView` which shows question number is showing that the question number is increasing but the question is not refreshing.
Like in the database I'm getting first question itself and the same options.
Here I guess the `updateQuestion()` method is not being called after buttonclick. please help

Database - https://ibb.co/emVEVo

Comment: You can put debugger and check whether the method is getting called or not.

Comment: you increase your `mQuestionNumber` but never use it to get appropriate question.

Comment: see the database reference... im using it

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `firebase database reference (mDatabaseReference)` is null so first of all check this. if it is `not null` then use debug log to check which line of `code is not working`.

Answer (score 0):

OK guys i figured out what was wrong... i had initialized database reference inside the onCreate instead of inside the method... sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 0):

Your *Firebase Database Reference* is getting the wrong tree.
In your image have more more *fathers* before "*Quiz*", there's *VwtdCRK...* before and other...
When you use `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()` it takes the **root** of your database. Should be like:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("rootNotShowingInimage")
    .child("VwtdCRK0AXQ2bnKe01fy8mYUPqs2").child("Quiz").child("Question"...
```